# Tags <> within interface class name

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-batch

I'm trying to learn Spring Batch, and the book provides example interface class, but the naming convention is throwing me off.

```
public interface ItemProcessor<I,O> {
O process(I item) throws Exception;
```

}

I have never before seen parameters in a class name. Do they serve an actual purpose or are they there just to serve as a guide? How would the following code differ if the class name were changed?

```
public interface ItemProcessor {
O process(I item) throws Exception;
```

}

Comment: That is a generic interface. Start from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to learn about it.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are talking about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

`I` and `O` are generic parameters for that class.

You can think of `ItemProcessor` as an "`ItemProcessor` of `I`s and `O`s".

The simplest way to get a hint on how generics work is to think of a class `Box`.

Now what's it a box **of**?

```
class Box<? extends Number>
```

... is a `Box` of `Number`s.

etc.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the identifiers inside of the <>s indicate that ItemProcessor uses Generics.

The second example of code wouldn't compile at all. With the I & O missing from the interface definition, their presence in the "process" method declaration would cause a compilation failure.

When you create an instance of ItemProcessor, you would supply concrete classes into those generic placeholders, like so:

```
ItemProcessor<String, Integer> processor = new ConcreteItemProcessor<String, Integer>();
Integer result = processor.process("hello world");
```

Or more likely, you would actually declare ConcreteItemProcessor as an implementation of ItemProcessor<String, Integer> in its class definition, so that the instantiation could be a bit shorter:

```
ItemProcessor<String, Integer> processor = new ConcreteItemProcessor();
```

Because you declared processor as a processor of Strings and Integers, any attempt to use a different kind of object would result in a compilation error. Which you want! Before generics, the only way to create a truly "generic" interface like this would have been to make ItemProcessor process and return "Objects" or something similar, which would compile but could result in runtime errors if you accidentally passed in the wrong thing. This way, you catch errors quicker but have to make your code a bit more verbose.